# Definition of "scolt"

Tags: meaning

We found a gravestone in Ashby MA. with an old word on it we could not understand.

> "Lot, son of ... was scolt to death Decr. 8, 1806, aged 2 years and 10 months.".

We are not sure what *scolt* means - has anyone else come across this word before?

Google was unhelpful.

Comment: For reference, I found an image of the grave [here](http://www.library.umass.edu/spcoll/galleries/mange/mange4.htm).

Comment: Ha ha! That's awesome...the Manning family gravestones are really bizzare...there was a Sally and Sarah Manning both married to "John Manning" and having children at all sorts of weird dates.  The internet claims there was a John Jr., but we found only one John in the whole graveyard--and even so, he would have been having children with someone in her mid fifties...

Comment: Even more interesting was that most of John Manning's children died at the age of three.  My wife and I wondered if there wasn't a genetic disorder going on...you should visit Ashby if you get a chance, although there's really nothing to do there except enjoy the graveyards.

Comment: Sally is usually a nickname for Sarah, so both names probably referred to the same woman.

Comment: It's fairly unusually to have multiple tombstones with different dates of death ;-)...Sarah is a pretty common name. My guess is he remarried another Sarah.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Scolt is an old variant of "scalded" - i.e. burnt by fluids. A Google book search finds spottings in [New England, 1793](http://books.google.com/books?id=w20jAQAAMAAJ&q=%2bscolt%20scalded&dq=%2bscolt%20scalded&hl=en&ei=_-89TpP7NoeChQfNhOW5Cw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&sqi=2&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAQ) and [Essex, England](http://books.google.com/books?id=CUUVAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA96&dq=%2bscolt%20scalded&hl=en&ei=_-89TpP7NoeChQfNhOW5Cw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&sqi=2&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%2bscolt%20scalded&f=false).

The *t/ed* pattern is common enough: burnt/burned, spilt/spilled etc; and in some British English accents, it can be hard sometimes to hear the difference between scald (burn with fluids) and scold (harshly reprimand)

Comment: How did you figure this out?

Comment: I +1ed already, but thanks for including information on the t/ed pattern.